# How i pass an entire path from python to c#?

Tags: c#, python, image, variables

I'm not very good with c# and i need a help. I create a python code for looping the file inside a folder, this is the code:

```
path = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\image\\')
images = os.listdir(path)
sorted_imgs = images.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))

for i, roi in enumerate(images):

    img = (path + roi)
    print(img)
```

And this gave me the path i want. Now i need to pass this path into a variable inside a c# script, where the name of the variable is 'image'. How can i do this?

Thank you for the help and for your time.

Comment: How are you invoking the C# script?  If from python, you could just ass it as a command-line argument (I assume C# can read command-line arguments, there is a Win32 API for it).

Comment: Oops!  *pass* it as a command-line argument (Freudian slip)

Answer (score 2):

At best you add a placeholder in the C# script like `###IMAGEPATH###`
and use something like

```
with open('script.cs', 'rt') as f:
    x = f.read

x.replace('###IMAGEPATH###', path_found)        

with open('script_2.cs', 'wt') as f:
    f.write(x)
```

Comment: But I admit, this solution looks pretty 80's :) A cleaner solution would be what @cdarke mentioned.